# UIPickerView and subclass Array in Swift 3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

I am new on Swift and Firebase, but I am building an app that uses in one view controller a picker view and the data to populate it comes from an Firebase structure that put data into an array with parameters stored in a subclass.

I can see all the data printed in the debugger console, (Firebase is OK running here) showing me that the array received data from Firebase (and I can insert new items using a method for this with a button in this new controller too), but it looks that the methods for pickerview (`numberOfCOmponents`, `numberOfRowsInComponent` and `titleforRow`) initialize before the `viewDidLoad`, where the method who brings the data from Firebase to the array occur, and I have a `count = 0`.

My pickerview stays empty. I have no crash. At the debugger console, I can see the printed `count = 0` and then, with a `print` placed at the end of `viewDidLoad` method, it counts how many registers I actually have and show them.

I want to know what should I do for the array be fulfilled with Firebase data before pickeview methods do it, and these data como to the pickerview rows. Thank you.

```
var refw2: [PickerArrayClasses] = []
@IBOutlet weak var pckProfessores: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let refW = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("avaliacao").child("equipe")
    refW.queryOrdered(byChild: "nomePreceptor").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        var newTeste2: [PickerArrayClasses] = []
        for resposta in snapshot.children {
            let itemsAadicionar = PickerArrayClasses(snapshot: resposta as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newTeste2.append(itemsAadicionar)
        }
        self.refw2 = newTeste2
        print("ITENS NO ARRAY RefW2 \(newTeste2)")
    })

    self.pckProfessores.delegate = self
    self.pckProfessores.dataSource = self
    self.pckAvaliador.delegate = self
    self.pckAvaliador.dataSource = self

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        print("CONTAR ITENS NO REFW2 - SECAO COUNT = \(refw2.count)")
        return refw2.count
 }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
   return refw2[row].nomePrecep
 }

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let PreceptorEscolhido = refw2[row].nomePrecep
     print("PRECEPTOR ESCOLHIDO: \(PreceptorEscolhido)")
}
```

Information at the Debugger Console

```
CONTAR ITENS NO REFW2 - SECAO COUNT = 0
ITENS NO ARRAY RefW2 
[ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("2222222222"), key: -KYiOkUH1cFXj7q7LkTi),
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("33333"), key: -KYiOvOjfxZpuUkxM4bn),
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("5555555555555555555"), key: -KYiPsHTumA0qdTKkbMT),
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("77777"), key: -KYikQ5dveM3L7JielTt), 
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("MARK BONINHA"), key: -KYi7XofWn9Um6FVV3M6), 
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("OUTRO MARK"), key: -KYi7t6OEllWTmMl655T), 
ChkList.PickerArrayClasses(nomePrecep: Optional("dfddf"), key: -KYiI8sTLE6G3olzOtAJ)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue adding the following line into viewDidLoad method:

```
self.pckProfessores.reloadAllComponents()
```

just after `self.refw2 = newTeste2` line.

Answer (score 0):

With my friends we solved this issue using blocks.

We create a class to manage all the firebase executions in this class we generate methods like:

```
class FirebaseManager {

    func monitor(surveyWithId id: String, handler: @escaping (Entity?) -> Void) -> Block {
        return observe(FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(Survey.path).child(id)) {
            snapshot in
            firebaseManagerQueue.async {
                guard let dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any] = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable: Any] else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            handler(nil)
                        }
                    return
                }
                let survey = Survey(id: snapshot.key, dictionary: dictionary)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    handler(survey)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So all you need to do after this is to call this method in your view controller:

```
firebaseManager.monitor(surveyWithId: surveyId) {
        [weak self] entity in
        guard let controller = self,
            let survey = entity as? Survey else {
                return
        }
```

And in this block you should be able to reload your pickerview.

In this code we are retrieving surveys from firebase

Comment: Thanks @Sebitas. I could solve it by now with just one line: `self.pckProfessores.reloadAllComponents()` inside viewDidLoad just after `self.refw2 = newTeste2`. Thanks anyway. I will study your answer and iam sure it will teach me a lot.